# Need help grasping some concepts about fork()

Tags: process, fork

So I have a couple of questions about fork():

1) I'm pretty sure that forking allows several threads to access a shared address space, which makes it really cheap for the system. I'm also pretty sure that each process is allocated stack space. Also, I don't believe that calling fork() created a new process image (which is created using exec(), as far as I know) Am I right in these assertions?

2) Now for an incredibly dense question: is calling fork() on a process tantamount to multithreading? Like if you fork() a parent process, do the parent and the child have their own thread?

3) if fork() replicates a parent process, how does the child know when to stop forking? I.e., you have the following simple code:

```
#include
int glob=6;
char buf[]="a write to stdout\n";
main()
{
   int var;
   int pid;
   var=88;
   printf("Before Fork\n");
   if((pid=fork())<0)
       printf("fork Error\n");
   else if(pid==0)
   {
       glob++;
       var++;
   } 
   else
       printf("\nPID= %d ,GLOB = %d,VAR = %d\n",getpid(),glob,var);
   exit(0);
}
```

(src http://allprograms-c.blogspot.com/2010/01/simple-fork-program-in-linuxunix-c.html)

What stops the child from forking again and again and again? Does the child process stop at the call to fork(), and the command fork() then returns the childs PID to the parent?

On a related note, how would you create a process whose children continue to fork?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short:

1. Forking does **not** allow a forked process  (it's child) to change the parents data. Once you fork a new process, it gets a **copy** of the parents process descriptor (it's data, file descriptors etc). Forking is not cheap. It is actually a very expensive operation due to the copying involved. Forked process is a copy of it's parent and the stack is also a copied. `exec()`  "only" loads and executes new code, since the "process image" as you refer to it is already created during the fork.
2. Forking a parent process creates a child process. The parent process can have threads, the child process can also have threads. Threads from the parent process cannot intervene with threads from the child process. On a dual core cpu, one core can run parent process, while the other core can run the child process in parallel. If the parent process has a thread running, then one core can run the parent process, while the other core can run the parent process's thread in parallel.
3. Read a book or find some tutorials. Understanding what happens when the fork system call should be crystal clear before doing anything else. A simple google search will give you pleanty of information, such as this [article](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html).